# Spark not able to create dataframe on transactional table

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hive, transactional

Why we use JDBC for creating dataframe for the transactional table in Hive and don't use Spark for creating dataframe on transactional table ?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Use dataframe with native support via spark.read ... or spark.sql .. against Hive table.

Comment: May be rephrase question.